# InAppBrowser executeScript fails in Ionic Pro on iOS devices

Tags: ionic3, ionic-view

I publish my Ionic 3 application in Ionic Pro. When I load this application through Ionic View, `executeScript()` not executed after the page has been loaded and no errors generated.
If I load my application directly to iPad, everything is ok and `executeScript()` works perfectly. My code:

```
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserOptions, InAppBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {    
  public browser: InAppBrowserObject;    
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser,) {  }

  start() {    
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      hidden: 'no',
      closebuttoncaption: 'Close',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      clearsessioncache: 'yes',
      zoom: 'no',
      location: 'yes'
    };   

    this.browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('http://test.com', '_blank', options);
    this.browser.show();

    this.browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(loadStopData => {
      this.log('loaderror');
    });

    this.browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(loadStopData => {          
      this.browser.executeScript({
        code:
          "var elemCl1 = document.querySelector('#partWelcome'); "        
      })
      .then( data => {    
          console.log('loadstop');  <-- never arises
      })
      .catch(e => {
            console.log('EXC 11', e);
      })        
...   

    });
  };
```

Is it my mistake or problem with Ionic View?